# How to create a recursive method for java classes with catalog structure?

Tags: java, recursion

I need to make a catalog structure with classes.
It must look like the following:

```
Group 
   1) Subgroup1
       1.1 subgroup1
               1.1.1 product1
               1.1.2 product2  
       1.2 subgroup2   
  2)  Subgroup2
       2.1 subgroup1
               2.1.1 product1
               2.1.2 product2  
       2.2 subgroup2
```

I have created three classes Group, SubGroup, and LeafGroup with such relation:

```
class Group { 
int id; 
String name; 
}

class SubGroup extends Group { 

List<Group> subgroups;
}

class LeafGroup extends Group { 

List<Product> products;
}
```

So, only Leaf Group has products.
I need to create a method for the group where each group will recursively get all available products.
For example. for  Subgroup2  available   2.1.1 product and  2.1.2 product.
As I understand it must check if the subgroup has products and if no, calls itself and check it in the next level.
Have can correctly looks this recursive method ?

Comment: Why do you split into three different types of groups?

Comment: Cause only the leaf group has products, others have a list of subgroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a Group without SubGroup and without Product is useless make Group abstract.
And give it an abstract function getProducts

```
abstract class Group { 
   int id; 
   String name; 
   public abstract List<Product> getProducts();
}
```

now you need to implement it for SubGroup and LeafGroup

```
class LeafGroup extends Group { 

    List<Product> products;

    @Override
    public List<Prodcut> getProducts() {
        return products
    }

}


class SubGroup extends Group { 

    List<Group> subgroups;

    @Override
    public List<Prodcut> getProducts() {
        // insert here the stream/flatmap 
        // or loop implementation of collectiong the products of the subgroups, 
        // as you can simply call getProducts on every group
        return ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hey friend as I think you have given parent and child classes. Your Parent class is Group and it is implemented by SubGroup class and LeafGroup class. So I think you are implementing individually by both of these classes. So you should first create any method in your Group class which must be overridden by these two classes.